# How do I create a drop down menu in Django as shown below?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, bootstrap-4

I'm following the instructions from the Django for Beginners book. I'm currently in chapter 13, trying to create my homepage to have a drop down nav bar in the top right and a loge with a create new article button in the top left. However, my code ends up putting the create new article button and the drop down bar both in the right. Moreover, the drop down bar does not show the expected options when I clicked on it.

This is written using Django 2.x.

Here's my code:

````
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Newspaper</a>
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
 data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false"
 aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
       <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'article_new' %}">+ New</a></li>
   </ul>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu"
       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         {{ user.username }}
       </a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
       aria-labelledby="userMenu">
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Change password</a>
       <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a>
       </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
 {% else %}
   <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
     <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Log in</a>
 <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary ml-2 ">Sign up</a>
   </form>
 {% endif %}
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
 aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>```

Here are the expected results:
 ![Expected](https://i.imgur.com/O92rHIH.png)
 ![Expected1](https://i.imgur.com/teyrG00.png)
Here's what I generated:
 ![Actual](https://i.imgur.com/wZ7JlXw.png)
````

Comment: 1) This isn't Django; it's html. 2) I can't help you without seeing the CSS. But the problem lays with the frontend, not the backend (Django).

Comment: sorry if I mislead you but what I'm trying to say is I've been following the tutorials from the book Django for Beginners. For this project, the author uses bootstrap css. Here's the part with bootstrap css:

Comment: ```  <head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf- ">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale= , shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
  crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>{% block title %}Newspaper App{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>```